# JS - Are arrays referenced?

Tags: javascript

Need some help in understanding arrays in JS - from some code i just tried below, it appears that they are referenced? Is this correct?

```
const generatedNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const shuffleArrayNumbers = shuffleArray(generatedNumbers);

shuffleArrayNumbers.shift();
console.log(shuffleArrayNumbers);
console.log(generatedNumbers);

function shuffleArray(array) {
    return array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}
```

So I was expecting as `shuffleArrayNumbers` is in its own variable it would behave unique, however that's not the case. The two console.log outputs produce the same output.

Could someone explain what's happening and how I can return a unique/new array.

Thanks.

Comment: Arrays are objects. To create a shallow copy, you can use `generatedNumbers.slice()`

Comment: `.sort()` sorts the array in place AND returns it. See [MDN docs: Array sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` method changes the array ([MDN: sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)).

You can create an independent array with the spread syntax ([MDN: spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)).

```js
const generatedNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const shuffleArrayNumbers = shuffleArray(generatedNumbers);

shuffleArrayNumbers.shift();
console.log(shuffleArrayNumbers);
console.log(generatedNumbers);

function shuffleArray(array) {
    return [...array].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Js's Arrays are references so when you do so :

```
let arr1 = [1, 2 ,3];
let arr2 = arr1;
arr2.pop();
// arr1 = [1, 2] and arr2 = [1, 2]
```

If you want to avoid this behavior, you have to use `copy` for exemple by using `slice` or `spread` operator :

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
let arr2 = arr1.slice();
// or
let arr2 = [...arr1];

arr2.pop();
// arr1 = [1, 2, 3] and arr2 = [1, 2]
```

Note: This method doesn't work with `array` of `nested object` as the `object` properties will still be a `reference`.

In this case you have to use `structuredClone` (no fully supported by browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) :

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = structuredClone(arr1);
```